# admin-on-rest with passport.js authentication?

Tags: passport.js, admin-on-rest

I am wondering why I cannot find any AOR and passport auth code online? I found a ton of keystone and passport though... Is there a specific reason for that - the two should work well together, right?

Comment: passport.js is a generic auth system for Node.js, if you want to use it with AOR, you should first choose your authentication provider or strategy.
Do you want a JWT-based authentication or a Facebook Connect?

You can implement all the authentication systems you want thanks to the AOR API: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there is no reason `admin-on-rest` would not work with `passport` -- however, there is a caveat:

It seems you are searching for a "passport + AOR" tutorial or guide, but one of the selling points of admin-on-rest is that it is truly agnostic to any authentication implementation. Therefore, you would implement a passport strategy of your choosing (jwt, oauth, http basic) within `admin-on-rest`'s `authClient.js`

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html